# Get Javascript object value by key

Tags: javascript

```
var Array = [];

{'DateOfBirth' : '06/11/1978',
 'Phone' : '770-786',
 'Email' : 'pbishop@hotmail.com' ,
 'Ethnicity' : 'Declined' ,
 'Race' : 'OtherRace' , }
```

I need to access the 'Race'  here.. how can i do it... Its an array which holds this data...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Thats not an array, its an object. You want to do something like:

```
var myObject = {
  'DateOfBirth' : '06/11/1978',
  'Phone' : '770-786',
  'Email' : 'pbishop@hotmail.com' ,
  'Ethnicity' : 'Declined' ,
  'Race' : 'OtherRace'
};

// To get the value:
var race = myObject.Race;
```

If the Objects are inside an array `var ArrayValues = [{object}, {object}, ...];` then regular array accessors will work:

`var raceName = ArrayValues[0].Race;`

Or, if you want to loop over the values:

```
for (var i = 0; i < ArrayValues.length; i++) {
    var raceName = ArrayValues[i].Race;
}
```

Good documentation for arrays can be found at the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Answer (score 2):

A few things here.

You do not use `Array`, moreover, `Array` is actually what you can call when creating an `Array`, which you overwrite.

Second, you have an `object` (`{...}`), but you do not assign it to something. Do you perhaps want to store it in a variable? (`var obj = {...}`)?

Thirdly, the last `,` should not be there since there aren't any more elements.

If you have stored it in a variable, you can access it like `obj.Race`.

Answer (score 2):

```
var myObject = {
  'DateOfBirth' : '06/11/1978',
  'Phone' : '770-786',
  'Email' : 'pbishop@hotmail.com' ,
  'Ethnicity' : 'Declined' ,
  'Race' : 'OtherRace'
};

// To get the value:
var race = myObject.Race;
//or
var race = myArray[index].Race;
```