# How to access part of an array in ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

In my ajax, the PHP side contains an array with 3 values. I'd like to put these 3 values into separate  input fields. How can I do this? How do I access the array sent from PHP?

My code so far:

**PHP**

```
    $total['tot1'] = $numwelds + $numconwelds + $mpcountrys ;
    $total['tot2'] = $numwelds + $numconwelds + $fortot2 ;
    $total['tot3'] = $numwelds + $numconwelds + $fortot2 / $fortot3; 
    $response = json_encode($total);
    header("Content-Type: application/json");  
    echo $response;
    exit;
```

**Jquery**

```
 jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
        (function($) {
        $(document).ready(function(){
           $('#formsubmit').click(function(){
          $.post(
          PT_Ajax.ajaxurl,
                {
               action : 'ajax-inputtitleSubmit',
               numberofwelds : $('input[name=numberofwelds]').val(),
               numberofconwelds : $('input[name=numberofconwelds]').val(),
               nextNonce : PT_Ajax.nextNonce
                },
          function( response ) {
              $("#totalone").val(response);
               $("#totaltwo").val(response);
                $("#totalthree").val(response);
                }
                );
              return false;
        }); 

        });
        })(jQuery);
        });
```

Comment: Your jQuery is oddly nested. You're already in a `document.ready`, and you open another `document.ready` inside an IIFE? You should get rid of `jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
        (function($) {`, everything before `$(document).ready`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing the Object values inside an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6650587/accessing-the-object-values-inside-an-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to convert json to object:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(response);
$("#totalone").val(obj.tot1);
$("#totaltwo").val(obj.tot2);
$("#totalthree").val(obj.tot3);
```

Or you can also use [`$.parseJSON()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) of jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

use like

```
$("#totalone").val(response["tot1"]);
$("#totaltwo").val(response["tot2"]);
$("#totalthree").val(response["tot3"]);
```